# Unable to import Firebase JS SDK with React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

In my React Native app, I am trying to use the Firebase JS SDK with Expo as mentioned in [this guide](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/), although after installing the dependencies via `expo install firebase`, I am unable to import modules from `firebase/auth`. Calling the respective methods like `getAuth()` results in the following error:

`TypeError: (0, _auth.getAuth) is not a function. (In '(0, _auth.getAuth)()', '(0, _auth.getAuth)' is undefined)`

I am also unable to import modules from `firebase/database`, `firebase/firestore` etc.

My project is set up using Typescript, but I also experienced this problem with a JS-only project.

I am able to import firebase from `firebase/app`, but not the respective modules:
[image]

edit: I am using `getAuth()` and the other methods in the following context:

```
React.useEffect(() => {

 if (response?.type === "success") {
  const { id_token } = response.params;

  const auth = getAuth();      
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const credential = provider.credential(id_token);
  signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
 }
}, [response]);
```

I am using Firebase 8.2.3.

Comment: Can you share complete that include usage of getAuth()? Also which version of Firebase have you installed ?

Comment: I updated the question, I am using Firebase 8.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import syntax you're using is for Firebase SDK version 9 and later. For version 8 and below, use:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
...
```

And then use the v8 syntax as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#web-version-8).

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I really don't get why the Expo guide is using SDK v9 syntax when `expo install firebase` installs v8. Also their latest SDK version (v42) is not even compatible with Firebase SDK v9 yet, so no idea what went through their minds when writing this guide/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatly latest expo sdk is not compatible with firebase9 and if you use this version of firebase you see tones of odd error use firebase version 8